Change of Basis to Transform a 3-D Polygon onto the X-Y Plane
Suppose I have a 3-D polygon with at least three coplanar points $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, ...  I want to reorient the polygon (i.e. transform $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, ... to $p'_1$, $p'_2$, $p'_3$, ...) so that it lies on the X-Y plane (Z = 0) and so that it's first edge $p_1p_2$ falls on a line segment $q_1q_2$ on the XY plane.  If it helps simplify the problem you can assume that the length of $p_1p_2$ is the same as the length of $q_1q_2$.  See the "before" and "after" images below for an example.
Although, ideally, I could do this in one step (i.e. develop a single transform matrix $M$ so that $p'_i =M \cdot p_i$), I'm not at all concerned about having to use multiple steps, specifically with regards to translations.
I'm pretty sure this is a "change of basis" problem, but my linear algebra skills are too weak to figure it out for myself (despite hours of attempts).  Can anyone help?



To my mind, the natural approach would involve not just a change of basis but also a translation. It would be helpful if you added more context to the question, for example so we know whether this transformation needs to fix the origin.

I hopefully clarified that, @Numeral.  Please feel free to edit if my explanation is incorrect or confusing.

This is possible for polygons with up to $4$ points.
It will helpful to have one of our points situated at the origin, so we'll begin with a translation $x\mapsto x-p_1$. Hopefully we can then find a matrix $M$ to move the points as desired, after which we can move the points back to the correct position via $x\mapsto x+p_1'$. So our transformation will hopefully look like $T(x)=M(x-p_1)+p_1'$.
To start with,  $T(p_1)=M(0)+p_1'=0+p_1'=p_1'$, so we only need to find M that acts nicely on the other points. That is:
$$T(p_2)=M(p_2-p_1)+p_1'=p_2' \implies M(p_2-p_1)=p_2'-p_1'$$
$$T(p_3)=M(p_3-p_1)+p_1'=p_3' \implies M(p_3-p_1)=p_3'-p_1'$$
$$T(p_4)=M(p_4-p_1)+p_1'=p_4' \implies M(p_4-p_1)=p_4'-p_1'$$
This gives a unique choice for M as follows.
Let $S$ be the matrix with columns $p_2-p_1$, $p_3-p_1$ and $p_4-p_1$. That is
$$S=\Big[ p_2-p_1\text{  }\text{  }\text{  } p_3-p_1 \text{  }\text{  }\text{  } p_4-p_1 \Big]$$
And let
$$S'=\Big[ p_2'-p_1'\text{  }\text{  }\text{  } p_3'-p_1' \text{  }\text{  }\text{  } p_4'-p_1' \Big]$$
The matrix $S^{-1}$ will take the columns of $S$ to the standard basis, and $S'$ takes the standard basis to its columns. So choose $M=S'S^{-1}$. This assumes that each $p_i$ is distinct.
Overall this gives:
$$T(x)=p_1'+\Big[ p_2'-p_1'\text{  }\text{  }\text{  } p_3'-p_1' \text{  }\text{  }\text{  } p_4'-p_1' \Big]\Big[ p_2-p_1\text{  }\text{  }\text{  } p_3-p_1 \text{  }\text{  }\text{  } p_4-p_1 \Big]^{-1}(x-p_1)$$

Okay, I figured it out:

Translate the original points of P so that $p_0$ is at the origin, i.e. $p'_i = p_i - p_0$.
Calculate the orthonormal basis for the translated polygon:
$$ u = p'_1 \\
U = u / ||u|| \\
w = p'_1 \times p'_2 \\
W = w / ||w|| \\
V = U \times W $$
Create the "untransform" matrix to convert polygon-basis to world-basis:
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 
U_x & U_y & U_z  \\
V_x & V_y & V_z  \\
W_x & W_y & W_z  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Translate the original points of $Q$ so that $q_0$ is at the original, i.e. $q'_i = q'_i - q_0$.
Calculate the orthonormal basis for line segment $Q$ on the XY plane (Z = 0):
$$qu = q'_1 \\
qU = qu / ||qu|| \\
qV = (qU_y, -qU_x, 0) \\
qW = (0, 0, 1) $$
Create the transform matrix to convert world coordinates to $Q$ coordinates:
$$qM = \begin{bmatrix}
U_x & V_x & W_x \\
U_y & V_y & W_y \\
U_z & V_z & W_z \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Transform and translate the polygon points:
$$p^{final}_i = (qM \cdot M \cdot p'_i) + q_o$$

A lot of optimization can be done to this, particularly with
the $q$-related transforms.  $M$ and $qM$ can be easily combined, with the resulting transform being:
Given $P = p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots$ ($p_i$ all coplanar) and $Q = q_1, q_2$ (with the $z$-coordinate = $0$):
$$ 
p'_i = p_i - p_1 \\
U = p'_1 / ||p'_1|| \\
W = (p'_1 \times p'_2) / ||p'_1 \times p'_2|| \\
V = U \times W \\
T \text{  (called $qU$ above)} = (q'_2 - q'_1) / ||q'_2 - q'_1|| \\
M = \begin{bmatrix}
T_x U_x + T_y V_x & T_x U_y + T_y V_y & T_x V_z + T_y V_z \\
T_y U_x - T_x V_x & T_Y U_y - T_x V_y & T_y V_z - T_x V_z \\
W_x & W_y & W_z
\end{bmatrix} \\
p^{final}_i = M \cdot p'_i + q_1
$$
